# requests: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable in python 3.1.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm making a web page scraper using `BeautifulSoup4` and requests libraries. I had some trouble with `BeautifulSoup` working but got some help and was able to get that fixed. Now I've run into a new problem and I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm using requests 2.2.1 and I'm trying to run this program on Python 3.1.2. And when I do I get a traceback error.

here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = input("Enter a URL (start with www): ")
link = "http://" + url
page = requests.get(link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for url in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(url.get('href'))
    print()
```

and the error:

```
Enter a URL (start with www): www.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/project.py", line 8, in <module>
    page = requests.get(link).content
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py3.1.egg/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py3.1.egg/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py3.1.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 349, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py3.1.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 287, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py3.1.egg/requests/models.py", line 287, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url,params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py3.1.egg/requests/models.py", line 321, in prepare_url
    url = str(url)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I've done some looking and when others have gotten this error (in django mostly) there was a comma missing but I'm not sure where to put a comma at? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match the [published version](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v2.2.1/requests/models.py#L321); the line number doesn't match and there is an extra comma in that line that should not be there. The exception suggests that `str` is bound to a *tuple*. What else was changed?

Comment: I apologize, i added the comma in the line url = str(url,) just to see what would happen. I'll fix it and edit

Comment: The line number still doesn't match. What is `print(repr(str))` showing?

Comment: @heyItsTy1992 Normally, it should not be needed to edit any "system-side" files.

Comment: I see what you mean now though, the code that i have it doesn't have url = unicode(url). What is there above is what was given to me. Should i try using unicode instead?

Comment: print(repr(str)) showed <class 'str'>

Comment: @heyItsTy1992: No, it means you do **not** have `requests` version 2.2.1 installed. Whatever you have there is at best an edited copy of the package. It makes it very hard to provide help here, too.

Comment: [where i got my requests library at](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)

Comment: @heyItsTy1992: sure, but line 321 in `models.py` the `requests-2.2.1.tar.gz` distribution doesn't match your traceback. The line you show is instead on line 324. Perhaps you have stale bytecode in that package; I'd uninstall and re-install it.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that we haven't tested on python 3.1 in several versions (since sometime in 1.x). If you want to use python 3 you should use 3.3.